Export or query for all requests SQL in database SQL in Azure Synapse
I need to analyse the quantity of SQL requests in views of DW database in Azure Synapse. In the tool there is a monitor of SQL requests, but not is possible export the data. There is a table where I can see this data, or other way to consult the quantity of SQL requests and export?
Example below.
enter image description here
I tried execute query default of SQL server, but the results differs from Azure Synapse Monitor.
examples: How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio
Last executed queries for a specific database
I tried the function Export-AzSynapseSqlScript like some documentations indicates, but the fucntion export all SQL scripts, without all requests SQL. Link of my question in Microsoft answers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1657187/export-or-query-for-all-requests-sql-in-dw-databas?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1509279#newest-answer-comment

I found a sys table what contains the result that I expected. The table sys.dm_exec_requests_history contains the same result of monitor of Synapse.
Source: Does azure synapse serverless sql pool database support Query store?
